# How do I pass or fail a job in SQL Server agent based on a return value from a stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-agent

What do I need to do in order to execute a step in a SQL Server 2012 agent job that returns a bit value back? Basically, I want to fail the job or pass to the next step based on the results from the execution of the stored proc.

Comment: Can you define "the results"? Do you mean whether it returns an error, or returns a specific return value, or outputs a specific output parameter value, or returns a specific resultset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evaluate the result from the proc (with an IF statement) and then if you want it to fail the job execute a THROW command. [See this article](http://sqlhints.com/2013/06/30/differences-between-raiserror-and-throw-in-sql-server/).